# How to insert into a table all dates and all months between year 2000 and 2020?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, sql-insert, bulkinsert, bulk

I have created a table called `time_range` in SQL Server 2008 with columns

```
date ID, Month ID, year ID
```

How can I bulk insert all the date, month, year into these columns from year 2000 to 2020? Is there any simple query to do this?

Please help thanks in advance.

From:

```
1/1/2000  | January  |2000
```

TO :

```
31/12/2020| December | 2020
```

Comment: It'seems that you just don't want even to try to do it....  Please, upload what you have done till now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursive CTE to do this:

```
with cte (dateId)
as (
    select cast('2000-01-01' as date)

    union all

    select dateadd(day, 1, dateId)
    from cte
    where dateId < cast('2020-12-31' as date)
    )
select dateId,
    datename(Month, dateId) as monthId,
    year(dateId) as yearId
from cte 
option (maxrecursion 0);  -- to remove the recursion limit
```

You can use this to do the insert into other table

Comment: GurV Thanks your help . Im a beginner and i did not know much about CTE thanks for your help  once again .Also i faced problem while inserting into new table "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" but i was able to resolve it buy changing the variable type for respective columns and now the new table has all the data .

Comment: Sure :) Thanks once again .